# How to configure Andengine, Andengine Tiled Map, Physics2DBox with Android Studio 0.8.9?

Tags: java, php, android, json

How to setup Andengine with Android Studio 0.8.9?
How to add Andengine TMX Tiled Map Extension?
How to add Andengine Physics 2D Box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a tutorial for this - How to add Andengine, Andengine Tile Map, Andengine PhysicsBox2D to Android Studio 0.8.9.

Here is the link, I hope everything works - https://docs.google.com/document/d/1zk2QjNiPvkj52G4qSVivEPrLfkCUVqmnCVH8TfsnER8/edit

ANDENGINE WITH ANDROID STUDIO 0.8.9

Note: I am using the AnchorCenter brach and TortoiseGit to get all the files.

1. Download Andengine from github using TortoiseGit: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine
2. After the dowload  use TortoiseGit to switch to branch GLES2-AnchorCenter
3. Create new project in Android Studio
4. Create new module:
5. Select File -> New Module -> Android Library
6. Set Application name to AndEngine
7. Set Module Name to AndEngine
8. Set Package Name to org.andengine
9. Set Minimum SDK 14
10. Target SDK 19
11. Compile with 19
12. Theme None
13. Keep clicking next until module is created (no difference what you pick)
14. Enter the folder where you have downloaded Andengine, enter src/org/andengine and copy all the files inside.
15. Paste the copied files into your new module in your project src/java/org.andengine. After pasting everything remove tha MainActivity that was created on default
16. Enter the folder where you have downloaded Andengine, copy AndroidManifest and paste it into your new module (src/main)
17. Add the module to the project:
18. Select File-> Project Structure -> app-> Dependencies
19. Click the “+” button and pick “Module Dependency”
20. Select from the list your AndEngine Module
21. Check your project gradle in app folder (build.gradle) and make sure you have a line like this under dependencies - compile project(':AndEngine')

You should now be able to use AndEngine in your project

ANDENGINE TMX TILED MAP EXTENSION WITH ANDROID STUDIO 0.8.9

Note: We do this the same way like with Andengine but we change a few things:

1. Download AndengineTMX from github using TortoiseGit: https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension
2. After the dowload  use TortoiseGit to switch to branch GLES2-AnchorCenter
3. Create new project in Android Studio
4. Create new module:
5. Select File -> New Module -> Android Library
6. Set Application name to AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension
7. Set Module Name to AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension
8. Set Package Name to  org.andengine.extension.tmx
9. Set Minimum SDK 14
10. Target SDK 19
11. Compile with 19
12. Theme None
13. Keep clicking next until module is created (no difference what you pick)
14. Enter the folder where you have downloaded AndengineTMX , enter src/org/andengine/extension/tmx and copy all the files inside.
15. Paste the copied files into your new module in your project src/java/org.andengine.extension.tmx. After pasting everything remove tha MainActivity that was created on default
16. Enter the folder where you have downloaded AndengineTMX, copy AndroidManifest and paste it into your new module (src/main)
17. Add the module to the project:
18. Select File-> Project Structure -> app-> Dependencies
19. Click the “+” button and pick “Module Dependency”
20. Select from the list your AndengineTMX Module
21. Check your project gradle in app folder (build.gradle) and make sure you have a line like this under dependencies - compile project(':AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension')

You should now be able to use AndEngineTMXTiledMapExtension in your project.

ANDENGINE PHYSICSBOX2D WITH ANDROID STUDIO 0.8.9

1. Download this file - http://d-h.st/FyC
2. Unzip the file
3. You should have 2 jar files, copy them to your project app/libs
4. Right click on andenginephysicsbox2dextension.jar and select “Add as library” (or something like this)
5. Open your build.gradle in your app folder
6. Under dependencies add compile files('lib/physicsbox2d_so_files.jar')

You should now be able to use PhysicsBox2D in your project.